# FastLED WS2812B with Esp8266 Wemos D1 mini shows 1 first led only

Tags: esp8266

I'm working with WS2812B LED Strip (and Ring), Esp8266 Wemos D1 mini and FastLED library. I want to show  leds with same solid color in every startup.
There is a strange behavior that only the first 1 Led lights up. The code is very simple:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 24
#define DATA_PIN D6

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
void setup()
{
  uint8_t i = 0;
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(50);

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
  }
  FastLED.show();  //1 show() lights up only first led
}

void loop() {
}
```

If I add one more show() call, it works as expected.

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 24
#define DATA_PIN D6

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
void setup()
{
  uint8_t i = 0;
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(50);

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
  }
  FastLED.show();   //1st show()
  FastLED.show();   //2nd show() works as expected
}

void loop() {
}
```

I'm not sure what the correct way to show LEDs is. This is just a short code from my bigger project, I made it minimal for debugging. Please help me this.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried example code that is included with the library?

Comment: @jsotola the example codes are color animation. I just want to show solid color. Could you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: does the example code work as expected?

Comment: @jsotola The example code animation run so fast so I don't know what the first color is expected.

Comment: I tried Blink example with little changes 
void loop() { 
  // Turn the LED on, then pause
  leds[0] = CRGB::Red;
  leds[1] = CRGB::Red;  //Added
  FastLED.show();
  delay(500);
  // Now turn the LED off, then pause
  leds[0] = CRGB::Black;
  leds[1] = CRGB::Black;  //Added
  FastLED.show();
  delay(500);
}

At start up, it shows only the first LED, after that 2 LEDs are blinking -> The same issue with mine

Comment: @hcheung it's not a proper way to put show() into for loop. As I mentioned, this is just a small part of my bigger project where has hundreds of leds. Moving show() into loop cause the system very slow

Comment: @hcheung as per my understanding, show() will clock ALL data out. It means if there is 500 leds, one show() will clock 500 data out. Therefore, if you put show() in loop, it will clock out 500*500 data - 250000 data which will cause system hanged up. Have you tried with lednum = 500 and print the execution time after a loop?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but I recall hearing/seeing/reading somewhere that you should "clear" (turn off) all LEDS (using .show()) before displaying what you want ... so, it kinda means that the minimum number of calls to .show would be two

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow... that's a useful information that I've never read before. Do you remember that the "clear" show() should be called everytime or just the first time in setup()?

Comment: just once in setup of course ... you don't want to keep "blanking" the LED, that would be annoying ... since most uses of WLED are in the `loop()`, most would not probably notice that the "first" `show()` doesn't work right ... but, again, I'm not 100% sure of the veracity of my comment

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, thank you very much for your information